# 'source' from alias does not work, but manual sourcing does

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, source

[image]

I have these lines **saved** on my .bash_aliases:

```
alias sss='source ~/.bashrc'
alias merc='source /usr/local/mermaid-bootload/environment-setup-cortexa7t2hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi'
```

When I invoke `merc`, this shows up:

```
bash: /usr/local/mermaid-bootload/environment-setup-cortexa7t2hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueab: No such file or directory
```

Notice that gnueabi in the prompt is missing an "i" which baffles me.

I can confirm that the source path is written correctly in `.bash_aliases` file (when I `cat` the file, or open it in `vi` or `nano`).

I can also manually source the file when typing out the same command manually -or- copying the exact line from `.bash_aliases` and middle-clicking on the terminal.

What gives? Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that there is another alias for `merc` that is loaded after `.bash_aliases` is sourced (perhaps later in your ~/.bashrc file)? what are the outputs of `alias merc` and `type -a merc`?

Comment: Is it caused by ARG_MAX, https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-arg_max-maximum-length-of-arguments/

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the suggestions! @steeldriver got to the root cause -- apparently `merc` is also in the ~/.bashrc file and it has that missing "i". Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say once you save the configuration you will need to open a new terminal window for the changes to take place. Since running `source .bashrc` will refresh the settings in your current shell without forcing you to open a new terminal. Or you should `source ~/.bashrc` once to make aliases available in current session.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your suggestion, I did run `sss` in the screenshot which is my alias for `source ~/.bashrc`. `.bashrc` in turn sources `~/.bash_aliases`. Apparently, I already have merc on my ~/.bashrc and it has the wrong alias.